# Erro ao capturar campo de um JSON?

Tags: php, json

Estou tendo um erro quando tento recuperar um campo de um `array`.

Segue o `json`:

```
{
      "data": {
        "messages": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "sender": "sender@locaweb.com.br",
            "recipient": "recipient@locaweb.com.br",
            "sent_at": "2015-01-22T18:17:53.586-02:00",
            "status": "delivered",
            "bounce_code": null,
            "subject": "teste"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "sender": "sender@locaweb.com.br",
            "recipient": "recipient@locaweb.com.br",
            "sent_at": "2015-01-22T18:17:53.686-02:00",
            "status": "bounced",
            "bounce_code": "5.1.1",
            "subject": "test2"
          }
        ]
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "http://api.smtplw.locaweb.com.br/v1/message_reports?end_date=2015-04-10&page=2&per=2&start_date=2015-01-01&status=all",
        "next": "http://api.smtplw.locaweb.com.br/v1/message_reports?end_date=2015-04-10&page=3&per=2&start_date=2015-01-01&status=all",
        "prev": null,
        "first": "http://api.smtplw.locaweb.com.br/v1/message_reports?end_date=2015-04-10&page=1&per=2&start_date=2015-01-01&status=all",
        "last": "http://api.smtplw.locaweb.com.br/v1/message_reports?end_date=2015-04-10&page=5&per=2&start_date=2015-01-01\u0026status=all"
      }
    }
```

Meu PHP esta assim:

```
$jsonObj = json_decode($VARIAVEL_COM_O_JSON);
$resposta = $jsonObj->data;

foreach ($resposta as $c) {
    echo "$c->recipient<br>"; 
}
```

O erro que ocorre:

> `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Library/WebServer/Documents/teste.php on line 24`

**Linha do erro:**

```
echo "$c->recipient<br>";
```

Preciso escrever todos os campos `recipient` do `array`?

Comment: Você está fazendo como se recipient estivesse dentro de data, ele está dentro de messages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No seu foreach coloca assim:

```
foreach ($resposta->messages as $c) {
    echo "$c->recipient<br>"; 
}
```

O que estava acontecendo é que seu foreach estava passando somente no índice data, então a primeira volta sempre retornava o array que estava atribuído ao índice messages, dessa maneira ele vai fazer um loop com esse array.

Comment: Ok deu certo, muito obrigado

Comment: Olá @HugoBorges, se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, marque ela como solução, para que outras pessoas também possam ser ajudadas.

Comment: amigo fin um teste aqui, no meu servidor local esta funcionando mas no servidor de produção da errado. eu atualizei a pergunta, tem como me ajudar?

Comment: @HugoBorges Claro que sim amigo, o novo erro tá dando quando ele tenta chamar a propriedade `data`, provavelmente a sua variável `$resposta` está chegando vazia ou com o formato diferente do que você espera, mas o ideal seria você criar uma outra questão para resolver isso, pois não tem a ver com o problema anterior!

Comment: o estranho e que é o mesmo código. mas vou criar outra pergunta

Comment: Sim, mas não tem a ver com o código, e sim antes de chegar ai, pois provavelmente essa variável que você da um `json_decode` tá vindo vazia, entendeu?

Comment: @HugoBorges cria uma outra questão e me manda o link pra eu poder te ajudar!

Comment: ok, vlw. segue o link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161921/problemas-as-recuperar-objeto-de-um-json

Answer (score 3):

Seu Json tem vários níveis
aqui tu só entra no nível 1

```
$resposta = $jsonObj->data;
```

dentro dele tem `messages` e`links`

você precisa dizer o próximo nível para fazer a iteração

```
foreach ($resposta->messages as $c) {
    echo "$c->recipient<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: amigo fin um teste aqui, no meu servidor local esta funcionando mas no servidor de produção da errado. eu atualizei a pergunta, tem como me ajudar?

Comment: Ele não reconhece como objeto, tu pode escrever com um var_dump($resposta) e ver se ele diz se é um objeto, caso com objeto tu não consiga, tente como array. no coloque true no segundo parametro. json_decode($VARIAVEL_COM_O_JSON,true);  e então tente, $c["recipient"].