# Problemas as recuperar objeto de um json

Tags: php

Bom tenho um arquivo em php que pega um array Json e recupera o campo recipient. O código esta funcionado 100% no meu localhost. Porém quando coloco ele online, ele não funciona.

Segue o json:

```
{
  "data": {
    "messages": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "sender": "sender@locaweb.com.br",
        "recipient": "recipient@locaweb.com.br",
        "sent_at": "2015-01-22T18:17:53.586-02:00",
        "status": "delivered",
        "bounce_code": null,
        "subject": "teste"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "sender": "sender@locaweb.com.br",
        "recipient": "recipient@locaweb.com.br",
        "sent_at": "2015-01-22T18:17:53.686-02:00",
        "status": "bounced",
        "bounce_code": "5.1.1",
        "subject": "test2"
      }
    ]
  },
  "links": {
    "self": "http://api.smtplw.locaweb.com.br/v1/message_reports?end_date=2015-04-10&page=2&per=2&start_date=2015-01-01&status=all",
    "next": "http://api.smtplw.locaweb.com.br/v1/message_reports?end_date=2015-04-10&page=3&per=2&start_date=2015-01-01&status=all",
    "prev": null,
    "first": "http://api.smtplw.locaweb.com.br/v1/message_reports?end_date=2015-04-10&page=1&per=2&start_date=2015-01-01&status=all",
    "last": "http://api.smtplw.locaweb.com.br/v1/message_reports?end_date=2015-04-10&page=5&per=2&start_date=2015-01-01\u0026status=all"
  }
}
```

O código ficou assim:

```
            <?php

    // Monta a consulta na API smtp da LocaWeb
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.smtplw.com.br/v1/messages?status=errors&start_date=2016-10-26&end_date=2016-10-26",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "x-auth-token: xxxxx"
      ),
    ));

    // Excuta consulta
    $resposta = curl_exec($curl);

    // Faz o parsing da string, criando o array
    $jsonObj = json_decode($resposta);
    $resposta = $jsonObj->data;

    // Navega pelos elementos do array
    foreach ($resposta->messages as $c) {
        echo "$c->recipient<br>"; 
    }

    // Fecha consulta
    curl_close($curl);
```

O estranho e que no meu servidor local, esta funcionando 100%. Porém no servidor de produção não funciona. O log fica assim:

```
[28-Oct-2016 10:04:36 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/teste.php on line 20
[28-Oct-2016 10:04:36 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/teste.php on line 23
```

As linhas com erros são:

```
$resposta = $jsonObj->data; (linha 20)
foreach ($resposta->messages as $c) { (linha 23)
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o porque? Lembrando que é o mesmo Json e o mesmo arquivo php.  A única coisa que muda e o servidor.

_______________________________ EDIT _______________________

Resolvi o problema com desabilitando o SSL

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
```

Comment: Amigo tem como você colocar a parte do código que você preenche a variável $resposta?

Comment: ok postei o arquivo php inteiro

Comment: cara, depois dessa linha `$resposta = curl_exec($curl);` coloca um `print_r($resposta); exit;` pra ver o que tá sendo atribuído a variável `$resposta`

Comment: O que você pode fazer também é pegar o json que você colocou aqui na questão e atribuir manualmente na variável `$resposta` e fazer um teste para ver se ele vai responder o que você espera, se ele responder corretamente significa que o problema está na requisição pra API

Comment: fiz esse teste, e notei que o erro esta na requisição pra API, vc sabe o que pode ser? pois na minha máquina local funciona 100%

Comment: Você debugou a variável `$resposta`? Ela retorna alguma coisa?

Comment: sim, ela fica em branca. o problema realmente e na requisição. só não entendo o porque funciona no meu localhost

Comment: Pois é, não entendi também, tenta usar essa ferramente aqui, pra ver se a requisição vai funcionar: http://wst.mytechlabs.com/

Comment: Você pode usar também no seu código ao invés do curl_exec: `curl_errno($resposta);` ou `curl_error($resposta);` pra tentar debugar mais a fundo.

Comment: No seu CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, tenta adicionar mais esse elemento no array: 'Content-Type: application/json'

Comment: tentei deixar ele assim: `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "x-auth-token: xxxx",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  ),` mas não deu certo

Comment: olha o erro que retorna `cURL Error #:Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates`

Comment: Tenta adicionar esses dois elementos no seu array: 

CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0

Comment: o problema era com o ssl mesmo, atualizei a pergunta, depois vc posta uma resposta para eu marcar ok

Comment: OK, vou criar a resposta pra formalizar então!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é com SSL, adicione isso no seu array de configurações para ignorar a verificação:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se vai te ajudar mas aqui funcionou de boa.

```
$obj = '{  
   "data":{  
      "messages":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "sender":"sender@locaweb.com.br",
            "recipient":"recipient@locaweb.com.br",
            "sent_at":"2015-01-22T18:17:53.586-02:00",
            "status":"delivered",
            "bounce_code":null,
            "subject":"teste"
         },
         {  
            "id":2,
            "sender":"sender@locaweb.com.br",
            "recipient":"recipient@locaweb.com.br",
            "sent_at":"2015-01-22T18:17:53.686-02:00",
            "status":"bounced",
            "bounce_code":"5.1.1",
            "subject":"test2"
         }
      ]
   },
   "links":{  
      "self":"http:\/\/api.smtplw.locaweb.com.br\/v1\/message_reports?end_date=2015-04-10&page=2&per=2&start_date=2015-01-01&status=all",
      "next":"http:\/\/api.smtplw.locaweb.com.br\/v1\/message_reports?end_date=2015-04-10&page=3&per=2&start_date=2015-01-01&status=all",
      "prev":null,
      "first":"http:\/\/api.smtplw.locaweb.com.br\/v1\/message_reports?end_date=2015-04-10&page=1&per=2&start_date=2015-01-01&status=all",
      "last":"http:\/\/api.smtplw.locaweb.com.br\/v1\/message_reports?end_date=2015-04-10&page=5&per=2&start_date=2015-01-01\\u0026status=all"
   }
}';


$jsonObj = json_decode($obj, true);
$resposta = $jsonObj['data'];

    // Navega pelos elementos do array
foreach ($resposta['messages'] as $c) {
    echo $c['recipient'] . '</br>'; 
}
```

Desculpa mas ainda não aprendi a formatar código aqui :-)

Comment: o problema está na requisição da API, como não funciona a variável `resposta` fica vazia.

Comment: Humm, entendi. Então é na api. Pensei que era no código.

Comment: vc sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Não. Eu geralmente faço minhas requisições usando Angular com $http. Nunca fiz usando CURL.